# Chrome-mobile "forgets" settings in indexedDb & local Storage

Tags: android, mobile-chrome

We got a website installed as a PWA (via intune) which needs a configuration to be saved on the device. In the begining the config was saved in the indexedDb and the devices would "forget" the config (aka seemingly delete the indexedDb) at random times. Some devices did this twice in a month, some devices havent had this problem since the software was introduced. About a month ago, we added a "backup" in the local storage directly and via a "config id".
So the software looks first into the indexed db, if nothing found, it looks into the local storage. If it cant find a config there, it reads the "config id" from the local storage and calls the server to get the config and saves it into the local storage and indexedDb.

But we had 4 cases in the past week where (different) devices needed to be setup again, or in other words, had an empty indexedDb and local storage.

Does anyone know what causes chrome to delete the data and how to prevent this?